# How do I launch an updater properly?

Tags: windows, winapi, language-agnostic

I've got a program that needs to be able to update itself.  I have a second program that will perform the updates, downloading and installing.  The updater will obviously need to be able to update the main program, and for that, the main program can't be running.  So I want to have the main program launch the updater with a call to `ShellExecuteEx`, but [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759784%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has me a little confused.

It says that:

> The SEE_MASK_NOASYNC flag must be specified if the ... process will
>   terminate soon after ShellExecuteEx returns. Under such conditions,
>   the calling thread will not be available to complete the DDE
>   conversation, so it is important that ShellExecuteEx complete the
>   conversation before returning control to the calling application.
>   Failure to complete the conversation can result in an unsuccessful
>   launch of the document.

And under `SEE_MASK_NOASYNC`, it says that the `ShellExecuteEx` call won't return until the operation is complete.  What I want is to launch the updater and then immediately terminate the main program, so the updater can run without trouble.  Is that the correct way to do it?  And is there anything special I need to do to keep the launched updater from being marked as a "child process" that will be killed when the main process shuts down?

Answer (score 4):

Do you have to call ShellExecute?  I do something similar and launch via CreateProcess and it works fine.

(In reality, cmd.exe is launched which runs a batch file.  The batch file waits, starts the updater and waits for it to finish, then waits a bit, then launches the main app again.  Never had any trouble with it)

Answer (score 1):

DDE won't be used to launch an EXE directly. (It's only used to launch certain types of files if they are regsitered as needing to be launched that way. If you're just running an EXE by name, DDE should be irrelevant.)

So you should specify SEE_MASK_NOASYNC (to make sure the ShellExecuteEx call finishes doing all it needs to do and your app is then free to end the thread as soon as the call returns) and the API should return very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

here's a good CodeProject article about launching an updater:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/395572/Executable-Integration-Example-External-settings-a